How can I use jetbrains gateway to develop python GUI on remote server?
here is my code, i'm using PiSimpleGUI, which uses tkinter to create a simple GUI,
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# 创建一个简单的窗口
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Hello, PySimpleGUI!')],
    [sg.Button('Click Me')]
]

# 创建窗口
window = sg.Window('Test PySimpleGUI', layout)

# 事件循环
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Click Me':
        break

# 关闭窗口
window.close()


but it seems that Gateway does not support x11?
error_image
so what should I do to show GUI on my computer(my server does not have a graphical desktop environment running)
may be use Xshell and Xmanager to run my test.py?

Problem solved.
I use Xmanager to recieve X11 from server, now run GUI.py in Jetbrains Gateway IDE can also show GUI on my desktop.
